# Polling rate of logitech m705 marathon mouse

Tags: mouse

Does anyone know what the polling rate is for the logitech m705 marathon mouse? I can't find this information anywhere on the web.

Comment: Most places suggest standard gaming ~ 1k

Comment: @DaveRook - It's not a gaming mouse, so if it's really 1K that's a pleasant surprise.

Answer (score 1):

Jeff Atwood has some great points on this article [Coding Horror:Mouse DPI and USB Polling Rate](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/04/mouse-dpi-and-usb-polling-rate.html) and has included a link to a tool to check your mouse polling [Direct input mouse rate tool](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/files/dx_mouse_timer_dialog.zip) that would be a help to your information quest on the m705.